# Transactional & Non-Transactional Cache in Java Persistence

Tags: java, caching, transactions, persistence, transactional

What is transactional cache and non-transactional cache?

And what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JPA supports different transaction isolation levels for caches which can be commonly classified into transactional and non-transactional.

Transaction isolation defines how the changes that are made by one operation become visible to other concurrent operations.

In a transactional cache, the changes from a transaction are committed to the cache as a single atomic unit. This means the objects/data are first locked in the cache (preventing other threads/users from accessing the objects/data), then updated in the cache, then the locks are released. Ideally the locks are obtained before committing the database transaction, to ensure consistency with the database.

In a non-transactional cache the objects/data are updated one by one without any locking. This means there will be a brief period where the data in the cache is not consistent with the database.

Some JPA providers may allow for configuration of their cache isolation to support fine-grained control over the consistency and isolation of the caches.

Comment: "This means there will be a brief period where the data in the cache is not consistent with the database." - the same can apply to the first one, the transactional cache as well. But you have written the main difference already: say you have 2 data tied together in a transaction, then the transactional will update the cache together with the 2 data, while the other is eventually consistent with the outcome of the transaction.